# Send button value with Ajax to Controller in .net core

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm going crazy trying to figure this one out.
First, I'm using entity framework and models etc. So, in my view I'm looping through all my objects, every object has unique properties - one of these properties i want to send to my controller, which does some things, and then reloads the page.

My controller class is as follows:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Modules.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LoadModule(string packageName)
        {
            //... do some things here
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

My view is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class="card border-secondary mb-3">                   
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="SendValue"
                                type="submit" value="@m.IntegrationPoint">
                                Execute Package
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Jquery/Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SendValue").click(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: '/ExampleModuleController/LoadModule',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{String:val}
    })
    .fail(function(){alert("fail")})
    .done(function(){alert("success")})

    });
    });
</script>
```

A link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6cwog72/1/) for easier view of html.

What am i doing wrong here? It doesn't even seem to register my button click or anything.

Comment: Can you show more code about your view?I cannot see the string packageName.

Comment: Hm, that is all my code. 
packageName is meant to be @m.IntegrationPoint from the view (Bad naming practise perhaps). 
This is the value in the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code to your view

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change the  `url: '/ExampleModuleController/LoadModule',`into `url: '@Url.Action("LoadModule", "ExampleModule")?IntegrationPoint=' + val ,`

Also , in Controller, change the parameter name to `string IntegrationPoint`in LoadModule action.

**Note**: Because the  `.fail(function(){alert("fail")})` in the front, so it will alert fail message.

result:

[image]